# How to use an anchor to prevent repetition of code sections?

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci

Say I have a number of jobs that all do similar series of scripts, but need a few variables that change between them:

```
test a:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - a
  interruptible: true
  rules: 
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
  script:
    - echo "env is $(env)"
    - echo etcetera
    - echo and so on
    - docker build -t a -f Dockerfile.a .
test b:
  stage: test
  tags:
    - b
  interruptible: true
  rules: 
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
  script:
    - echo "env is $(env)"
    - echo etcetera
    - echo and so on
    - docker build -t b -f Dockerfile.b .
```

All I need is to be able to define e.g.

```
- docker build -t ${WHICH} -f Dockerfile.${which} .
```

If only I could make an anchor like:

```
.x: &which_ref
  - echo "env is $(env)"
  - echo etcetera
  - echo and so on
  - docker build -t $WHICH -f Dockerfile.$WHICH .
```

And include it there:

```
test a:
  script:
    - export WHICH=a
    <<: *which_ref
```

This doesn't work and in a yaml validator I get errors like

```
Error: YAMLException: cannot merge mappings; the provided source object is unacceptable
```

I also tried making an anchor that contains some entries under `script` inside of it:

```
.x: &which_ref
  script:
    - echo "env is $(env)"
    - echo etcetera
    - echo and so on
    - docker build -t $WHICH -f Dockerfile.$WHICH .
```

This means I have to include it from one step higher up. So this does not error, but all this accomplishes is cause the later declared `script` section to override the first one.

So I'm losing hope. It seems like I will just need to abstract the sections away into their own shell scripts and call them with arguments or whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The YAML [merge key `<<`](https://yaml.org/type/merge.html) is a *non-standard* extension for YAML 1.1, which has been superseded by YAML 1.2 about 14 years ago. Usage is discouraged.

The merge key works on mappings, not on sequences. It cannot deep-merge. Thus what you want to do is not possible to implement with it.

Generally, YAML isn't designed to *process* data, it just loads it. The merge key is an outlier and didn't find its way into the standard for good reasons. You need a pre- or postprocessor to do complex processing, and Gitlab CI doesn't offer anything besides simple variable expension, so you're out of luck.

Comment: I realized there is something that we can use to work around this. There's `before_script` and `script`, (there might be an `after_script` too?) so sometimes it'll be possible to separate these and get desired behavior by working around the fact that the expansion clobbers previously defined script sections.

Comment: Sharing `before_script` with aliases and having different `script` values might indeed be a workaround.  I don't know GitLab CI well enough to give an informed opinion on it but from the YAML side there shouldn't be problems.